# appending data after reading from excel file in selenium web driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, excel

I have written a script which reads data from excel file and I use sendKeys method to input that data to textbox. Now I want to append/concatenate data after reading from excel and than resultant string I want to send as input to textbox using selenium webdriver following is code snippet

following code read data as "john" I want to append "john@example.com" after reading from excel and want to send it as input to textbox for "FName"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountName']")).sendKeys(objExcel.getCellData("FName", i));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sendKeys(objExcel.getCellData("Fname",i) + "@example.com");
```

Hope I understood your question correctly (just wondering).

Comment: yes I've already managed to do it on my own, however thank you for your response!